# Singularity of two measures is equivalent to the only measure being dominated by both measures is the zero measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at the proof of the Lebesgue decomposition theorem. Let $\mu,\nu$ be finite measures.

Here, they first define a measure $\nu^o$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. Now they set $\nu^\perp := \nu - \nu^o$, and show that $\nu^o$ is maximal among all measures $\rho$ such that $\rho \le \nu$ and $\rho \ll \mu$.

Using this they show Orthogonality. Let $\tau$ be a measure such that $\tau \le \mu$ and $\tau \le \nu^\perp$. Clearly, this implies that $\nu^o + \tau \le \nu$ and $\nu^o + \tau \ll \mu$. By the maximality, $\nu^o + \tau \le \nu^o$ and we conclude that $\tau = 0$ and $\nu^\perp \perp \mu$.

I don't follow the final line. How does $\tau=0$ conclude that $\nu^\perp \perp \mu$?

Comment: Do you mean $\ll$ instead of $\leq$? I'm not sure if I understand the question. If $\tau=0$ the whole situation is trivial and $\nu$ and $\mu$ need not be related whatsoever.

Comment: @IvoTerek I fixed the question.

Comment: @IvoTerek it is common to denote $\leq$ in lieu of $\ll$ because, well, absolute continuity is a transitive and reflexive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ positive measures. Let $f$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ w.r.t. $\mu+\nu^{\perp}$ and $g$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu^{\perp}$ w.r.t. $\mu+\nu^{\perp}$. Let $\tau (E)=\int_E \min \{f,g\} d (\mu+\nu^{\perp})$. Then $\tau \leq \mu$ and $\tau \leq \nu^{\perp}$ so $\tau =0$. Hence $\int_E  \min \{f,g\}d(\mu+\nu^{\perp})=0$ for every measurable set $E$ which implies $\min \{f,g\}=0$ almost everywhere w.r.t. $\mu+\nu^{\perp}$ (hence w.r.t. each of $\mu$ and $\nu^{\perp})$.  This means one of $f,g$ is $0$ at every point excluding a null set w.r.t. each of $\mu$ and $\nu^{\perp}$. Can you now prove that $\mu \perp \nu^{\perp}$?

Comment: So we may have $f=0$ on a set $N^c$ for which $\mu(N)=\nu^\perp (N)=0$. I don't see how to guarantee $\mu(N) = \nu^\perp (N^c)=0$ from this.

Comment: @takecare $\mu \{f=0\}=0$ and $\nu^{\perp} \{g=0\}=0$. And $(\mu+\nu^{\perp}) (A\cup B)^{c}=0$ where $A=\{f=0\}$ and $B=\{g=0\}$. $\mu$ is concentrated on $A^{c}$, $\nu^{\perp}$ on  $\{g\neq 0, fg=0\}$ and these two are disjoint sets.

Comment: I can see we should always have $(\mu + \nu^\perp) (A \cup B)^c = 0$ but why is $\mu (A) = 0$ and $\nu^\perp(B)=0$? And how do these give $\mu \perp \nu^\perp$?

Comment: @takecare $\mu (A) =\int_{A} f d(\mu+\nu^{\perp})$ by definition of RND so $\mu(A)=0$.